# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url_as'

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

i am making an image command and it didnt work. I am using Pillow but i don't think its the problem. Please help me

Here is the code:

```
@commands.command()
async def chad(self, ctx, user: nextcord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
    
    chad = Image.open(os.path.join("Modules", "Images", "chad.jpg"))
    useravatar = user.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    avatar_data = BytesIO(await useravatar.read())
    pfp = Image.open(avatar_data)
    pfp = pfp.resize((81,81))

    chad.paste (pfp, (282,247))
    chad.save("chad_done.jpg")

    await ctx.send(file = nextcord.File("chad_done.jpg"))`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

[`nextcord.Member`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) object hasn't `avatar_url_as` method

Probably you looking for [`nextcord.Member.avatar`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.Member.avatar)

Or [`nextcord.Member.display_avatar`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.Member.avatar)